# Problems with training my own dataset using the official DDPM-seg code

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, pre-trained-model

When I was trying to train my data set using the DDPM-seg official code, the problem occurred while loading the pre-trained model.
Error reported as follows

```
Creating DDPM Feature Extractor...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ddpm-segmentation-master/train_mydata.py", line 658, in <module>
    train(opts)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ddpm-segmentation-master/train_mydata.py", line 561, in train
    features, labels = prepare_data(args)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ddpm-segmentation-master/train_mydata.py", line 526, in prepare_data
    feature_extractor = create_feature_extractor(**args)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ddpm-segmentation-master/train_mydata.py", line 49, in create_feature_extractor
    feature_extractor = FeatureExtractorDDPM(**kwargs)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ddpm-segmentation-master/train_mydata.py", line 106, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ddpm-segmentation-master/train_mydata.py", line 87, in __init__
    self._load_pretrained_model(model_path, **kwargs)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/ddpm-segmentation-master/train_mydata.py", line 126, in _load_pretrained_model
    self.model.load_state_dict(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1497, in load_state_dict
    raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for UNetModel:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "input_blocks.4.0.skip_connection.weight", "input_blocks.4.0.skip_connection.bias", "input_blocks.4.1.norm.weight", "input_blocks.4.1.norm.bias", "input_blocks.4.1.qkv.weight", "input_blocks.4.1.qkv.bias", "input_blocks.4.1.proj_out.weight", "input_blocks.4.1.proj_out.bias", "input_blocks.5.1.norm.weight", "input_blocks.5.1.norm.bias", "input_blocks.5.1.qkv.weight", "input_blocks.5.1.qkv.bias", "input_blocks.5.1.proj_out.weight", "input_blocks.5.1.proj_out.bias", "input_blocks.7.1.norm.weight", "input_blocks.7.1.norm.bias", "input_blocks.7.1.qkv.weight", "input_blocks.7.1.qkv.bias", "input_blocks.7.1.proj_out.weight", "input_blocks.7.1.proj_out.bias", "input_blocks.8.1.norm.weight", "input_blocks.8.1.norm.bias", "input_blocks.8.1.qkv.weight", "input_blocks.8.1.qkv.bias", "input_blocks.8.1.proj_out.weight", "input_blocks.8.1.proj_out.bias", "input_blocks.10.0.skip_connection.weight", "input_blocks.10.0.skip_connection.bias". 
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "input_blocks.12.0.in_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.12.0.in_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.12.0.in_layers.2.weight", "input_blocks.12.0.in_layers.2.bias", "input_blocks.12.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "input_blocks.12.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "input_blocks.12.0.out_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.12.0.out_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.12.0.out_layers.3.weight", "input_blocks.12.0.out_layers.3.bias", "input_blocks.13.0.in_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.13.0.in_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.13.0.in_layers.2.weight", "input_blocks.13.0.in_layers.2.bias", "input_blocks.13.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "input_blocks.13.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "input_blocks.13.0.out_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.13.0.out_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.13.0.out_layers.3.weight", "input_blocks.13.0.out_layers.3.bias", "input_blocks.13.0.skip_connection.weight", "input_blocks.13.0.skip_connection.bias", "input_blocks.13.1.norm.weight", "input_blocks.13.1.norm.bias", "input_blocks.13.1.qkv.weight", "input_blocks.13.1.qkv.bias", "input_blocks.13.1.proj_out.weight", "input_blocks.13.1.proj_out.bias", "input_blocks.14.0.in_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.14.0.in_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.14.0.in_layers.2.weight", "input_blocks.14.0.in_layers.2.bias", "input_blocks.14.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "input_blocks.14.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "input_blocks.14.0.out_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.14.0.out_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.14.0.out_layers.3.weight", "input_blocks.14.0.out_layers.3.bias", "input_blocks.14.1.norm.weight", "input_blocks.14.1.norm.bias", "input_blocks.14.1.qkv.weight", "input_blocks.14.1.qkv.bias", "input_blocks.14.1.proj_out.weight", "input_blocks.14.1.proj_out.bias", "input_blocks.15.0.in_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.15.0.in_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.15.0.in_layers.2.weight", "input_blocks.15.0.in_layers.2.bias", "input_blocks.15.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "input_blocks.15.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "input_blocks.15.0.out_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.15.0.out_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.15.0.out_layers.3.weight", "input_blocks.15.0.out_layers.3.bias", "input_blocks.16.0.in_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.16.0.in_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.16.0.in_layers.2.weight", "input_blocks.16.0.in_layers.2.bias", "input_blocks.16.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "input_blocks.16.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "input_blocks.16.0.out_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.16.0.out_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.16.0.out_layers.3.weight", "input_blocks.16.0.out_layers.3.bias", "input_blocks.16.1.norm.weight", "input_blocks.16.1.norm.bias", "input_blocks.16.1.qkv.weight", "input_blocks.16.1.qkv.bias", "input_blocks.16.1.proj_out.weight", "input_blocks.16.1.proj_out.bias", "input_blocks.17.0.in_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.17.0.in_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.17.0.in_layers.2.weight", "input_blocks.17.0.in_layers.2.bias", "input_blocks.17.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "input_blocks.17.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "input_blocks.17.0.out_layers.0.weight", "input_blocks.17.0.out_layers.0.bias", "input_blocks.17.0.out_layers.3.weight", "input_blocks.17.0.out_layers.3.bias", "input_blocks.17.1.norm.weight", "input_blocks.17.1.norm.bias", "input_blocks.17.1.qkv.weight", "input_blocks.17.1.qkv.bias", "input_blocks.17.1.proj_out.weight", "input_blocks.17.1.proj_out.bias", "output_blocks.12.0.in_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.12.0.in_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.12.0.in_layers.2.weight", "output_blocks.12.0.in_layers.2.bias", "output_blocks.12.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "output_blocks.12.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "output_blocks.12.0.out_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.12.0.out_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.12.0.out_layers.3.weight", "output_blocks.12.0.out_layers.3.bias", "output_blocks.12.0.skip_connection.weight", "output_blocks.12.0.skip_connection.bias", "output_blocks.13.0.in_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.13.0.in_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.13.0.in_layers.2.weight", "output_blocks.13.0.in_layers.2.bias", "output_blocks.13.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "output_blocks.13.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "output_blocks.13.0.out_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.13.0.out_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.13.0.out_layers.3.weight", "output_blocks.13.0.out_layers.3.bias", "output_blocks.13.0.skip_connection.weight", "output_blocks.13.0.skip_connection.bias", "output_blocks.14.0.in_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.14.0.in_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.14.0.in_layers.2.weight", "output_blocks.14.0.in_layers.2.bias", "output_blocks.14.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "output_blocks.14.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "output_blocks.14.0.out_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.14.0.out_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.14.0.out_layers.3.weight", "output_blocks.14.0.out_layers.3.bias", "output_blocks.14.0.skip_connection.weight", "output_blocks.14.0.skip_connection.bias", "output_blocks.14.1.in_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.14.1.in_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.14.1.in_layers.2.weight", "output_blocks.14.1.in_layers.2.bias", "output_blocks.14.1.emb_layers.1.weight", "output_blocks.14.1.emb_layers.1.bias", "output_blocks.14.1.out_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.14.1.out_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.14.1.out_layers.3.weight", "output_blocks.14.1.out_layers.3.bias", "output_blocks.15.0.in_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.15.0.in_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.15.0.in_layers.2.weight", "output_blocks.15.0.in_layers.2.bias", "output_blocks.15.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "output_blocks.15.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "output_blocks.15.0.out_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.15.0.out_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.15.0.out_layers.3.weight", "output_blocks.15.0.out_layers.3.bias", "output_blocks.15.0.skip_connection.weight", "output_blocks.15.0.skip_connection.bias", "output_blocks.16.0.in_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.16.0.in_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.16.0.in_layers.2.weight", "output_blocks.16.0.in_layers.2.bias", "output_blocks.16.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "output_blocks.16.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "output_blocks.16.0.out_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.16.0.out_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.16.0.out_layers.3.weight", "output_blocks.16.0.out_layers.3.bias", "output_blocks.16.0.skip_connection.weight", "output_blocks.16.0.skip_connection.bias", "output_blocks.17.0.in_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.17.0.in_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.17.0.in_layers.2.weight", "output_blocks.17.0.in_layers.2.bias", "output_blocks.17.0.emb_layers.1.weight", "output_blocks.17.0.emb_layers.1.bias", "output_blocks.17.0.out_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.17.0.out_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.17.0.out_layers.3.weight", "output_blocks.17.0.out_layers.3.bias", "output_blocks.17.0.skip_connection.weight", "output_blocks.17.0.skip_connection.bias", "output_blocks.11.1.in_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.11.1.in_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.11.1.in_layers.2.weight", "output_blocks.11.1.in_layers.2.bias", "output_blocks.11.1.emb_layers.1.weight", "output_blocks.11.1.emb_layers.1.bias", "output_blocks.11.1.out_layers.0.weight", "output_blocks.11.1.out_layers.0.bias", "output_blocks.11.1.out_layers.3.weight", "output_blocks.11.1.out_layers.3.bias". 
    size mismatch for input_blocks.4.0.in_layers.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256, 256, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 256, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.4.0.in_layers.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.4.0.emb_layers.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1024, 1024]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.4.0.emb_layers.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1024]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.4.0.out_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.4.0.out_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.4.0.out_layers.3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256, 256, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.4.0.out_layers.3.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.5.0.in_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.5.0.in_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.5.0.in_layers.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256, 256, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.5.0.in_layers.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.5.0.emb_layers.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1024, 1024]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.5.0.emb_layers.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1024]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.5.0.out_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.5.0.out_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.5.0.out_layers.3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256, 256, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.5.0.out_layers.3.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.6.0.in_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.6.0.in_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.6.0.in_layers.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256, 256, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.6.0.in_layers.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.6.0.emb_layers.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1024, 1024]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.6.0.emb_layers.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1024]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.6.0.out_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.6.0.out_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.6.0.out_layers.3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256, 256, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.6.0.out_layers.3.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.in_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.in_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.in_layers.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 256, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768, 512, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.in_layers.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.emb_layers.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1536, 1024]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.emb_layers.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1536]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.out_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.out_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.out_layers.3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768, 768, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.out_layers.3.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.skip_connection.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 256, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768, 512, 1, 1]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.7.0.skip_connection.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.8.0.in_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.8.0.in_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.8.0.in_layers.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768, 768, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.8.0.in_layers.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.8.0.emb_layers.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1536, 1024]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.8.0.emb_layers.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1536]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.8.0.out_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.8.0.out_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.8.0.out_layers.3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768, 768, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.8.0.out_layers.3.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.9.0.in_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.9.0.in_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.9.0.in_layers.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768, 768, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.9.0.in_layers.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.9.0.emb_layers.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1536, 1024]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.9.0.emb_layers.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1536]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.9.0.out_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.9.0.out_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.9.0.out_layers.3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768, 768, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.9.0.out_layers.3.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.10.0.in_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.10.0.in_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.10.0.in_layers.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1024, 768, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for input_blocks.10.0.in_layers.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1024]).
··········
    size mismatch for output_blocks.6.0.skip_connection.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 1536, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 1280, 1, 1]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.8.0.in_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.8.0.in_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.8.0.in_layers.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 1024, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 768, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.8.0.skip_connection.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 1024, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 768, 1, 1]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.in_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.in_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([768]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.in_layers.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 1024, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 768, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.in_layers.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.emb_layers.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 1024]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.emb_layers.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.out_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.out_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.out_layers.3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 256, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.out_layers.3.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.skip_connection.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 1024, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 768, 1, 1]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.9.0.skip_connection.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.in_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.in_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.in_layers.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 1024, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 512, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.in_layers.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.emb_layers.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 1024]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.emb_layers.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.out_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.out_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.out_layers.3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 256, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.out_layers.3.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.skip_connection.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 1024, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 512, 1, 1]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.10.0.skip_connection.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.in_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([768]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.in_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([768]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.in_layers.2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 768, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 512, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.in_layers.2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.emb_layers.1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 1024]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.emb_layers.1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.out_layers.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.out_layers.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.out_layers.3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 256, 3, 3]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.out_layers.3.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.skip_connection.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 768, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256, 512, 1, 1]).
    size mismatch for output_blocks.11.0.skip_connection.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([256]).
```

The code where the error occurred is

```
    def _load_pretrained_model(self, model_path, **kwargs):
        import inspect
        import guided_diffusion.guided_diffusion.dist_util as dist_util
        from guided_diffusion.guided_diffusion.script_util import create_model_and_diffusion
        from collections import OrderedDict
        # Needed to pass only expected args to the function
        argnames = inspect.getfullargspec(create_model_and_diffusion)[0]
        expected_args = {name: kwargs[name] for name in argnames}
        self.model, self.diffusion = create_model_and_diffusion(**expected_args)

        self.model.load_state_dict(
            dist_util.load_state_dict(model_path, map_location="cpu")
        )

        self.model.to(dist_util.dev())
        if kwargs['use_fp16']:
            self.model.convert_to_fp16()
        self.model.eval()
```

The

```
load_state_dict
```

code in the code is

```
def load_state_dict(path, **kwargs):
    """
    Load a PyTorch file without redundant fetches across MPI ranks.
    """
    chunk_size = 2 ** 30  # MPI has a relatively small size limit
    if MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank() == 0:
        with bf.BlobFile(path, "rb") as f:
            data = f.read()
        num_chunks = len(data) // chunk_size
        if len(data) % chunk_size:
            num_chunks += 1
        MPI.COMM_WORLD.bcast(num_chunks)
        for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size):
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.bcast(data[i : i + chunk_size])
    else:
        num_chunks = MPI.COMM_WORLD.bcast(None)
        data = bytes()
        for _ in range(num_chunks):
            data += MPI.COMM_WORLD.bcast(None)

    return th.load(io.BytesIO(data), **kwargs)
```

I have been puzzled by this question for a long time, and I hope it can be answered. This question is very important to me, thank you for your help!

I checked all kinds of sources. Nothing.